# MD5 hash of string as key for array

Tags: php, md5

I am looking to have some values for a string, and wanted to get some sort of key for an array to hold its' values eg: "This is a test"

```
$tmpAr['ce114e4501d2f4e2dcea3e17b546f339'] = array("somevar" => "somedata", "morevar" => "moredata");
```

The reason I would like to do it this way, is because I don't know exactly what text will be used as the key, and rather then strip every possible problematic piece, the hash would take care of it.

There will likely be less then 100 strings in each grouping, so the likely hood of duplicate keys is very small.

Is there any issue with using this?

Comment: Unclear what you mean about "stripping possibly problematic pieces". Please explain more. In particular, a hash is extremely sensitive to small changes in the data.

Comment: @Thilo - *a hash is extremely sensitive to small changes* - No kidding.

Comment: If the string that is being used as the key has a line break in it, it can cause unpredictable results. I don't like the idea of stripping out all of the "bad" characters to create the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good method because you can have [key collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities). As you can read from wikipedia

> MD5 is not [collision resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant)

In general, using the hashing function to create key is never a good choise because of the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). The key collisions will cause an override of the values in that array position and this behavior will be very hard to debug. Thus, you'll run in serious problems and headache.

In conclusion, I suggest you to think another way to create your keys that will ensure you the uniqueness of the latters.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: What is wrong with using the input string itself as a key? We need more clarification about these "problematic pieces", why they are problematic, and how a hash takes care of them.

Comment: @Thilo - I don't remember saying there was anything wrong with that. In review, "what is the *suggested* answer?"

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - Admittedly, we are (at least by your answer) on opposite sides of this, since I don't see anything wrong with using MD5 to generate a pseudo-random array key. All I have to say is, "What else is there that is *actually* random?"

Comment: Show me the odds. Show me a *provably better way*.

Comment: I think it would just be better if you just use the ordinary index rather than complicating the whole process, anyway if you need to search some data on the array there are actually functions on php that would manage to do that for you for faster results. ;)

Comment: I have suggested an option already and using the ordinary index starting from 0 and so on were just trying to help you cause you raise a question here if you think we don't provide the right answer it's ok. :)

Comment: @Thilo - No problem, freedom is messy.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - See my original comment on the question. I don't think it's a problem to do what the OP suggests. It is what it is.

Comment: This question brought to you by Don Quixote.

Comment: Some of the problematic data is special characters, line breaks etc.. I wanted to simplify the process by creating a hash key to make it easier to find what I am looking for in the array, and unless I know the index based on the string a general index just won't work. 

While I understand that there is a chance that there could be a collision, I am not totally convinced by the wiki article, that in such a small subset of data this will come up.

I would definitely love to hear other ideas, as I need to look in the array based on the string and using an array search is too slow.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - I know you're pretty rigid in your understanding, but if you wish to one day be making decisions, you oftentimes have to balance the bad with the good and make a best (*guess*) about what is the right way to go. Saying, "Hell no, this isn't right" is not how a leader leads. You have to be able to show at least where to go from there. "It is what is it is" oftentimes means "This is what I found and this is how I am affecting change". Don't tell me how you plan to *block progress*, tell me how you will *affect progress*.